# Not displaying tally ledgers in datagridview

Tags: vb.net, odbc, tally

Tried to list all the ledgers from tally through odbc. got nothing. Mycode is as follows,
no errors while executing. but not displaying the list of ledgers into the datagridview1

```
  Try

        Dim TalCon As OdbcConnection

        TalCon = New OdbcConnection("DSN=TallyODBC_9000;PORT=9000;DRIVER=Tally ODBC Driver;SERVER={(local)}")

        Dim Taldr As OdbcDataReader


        Dim cmd As New OdbcCommand("SELECT $Name FROM Ledger")

        TalCon.Open()

        cmd.Connection = TalCon

        Taldr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        While Taldr.Read
            DataGridView1.DataSource = Taldr


        End While

        'displaying connection name to verify
        TextBox1.Text = TalCon.ToString

        Taldr.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Master " & vbCrLf & ex.Message)
    End Try




End Sub
```

Comment: `dim dt as new DataTable dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader()) DataGridView1.DataSource = dt`. The DataReader needs to be closed (before the Connection).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am curious what database you are using that requires ODBC and does not have a specific provider.

I have divided your code into user interface code and database code. This makes it easier to maintain.

Database objects like Connection, Command, and DataReader must be closed and disposed. `Using...End Using` blocks take care of this even it there is an error.

You can pass the `CommandText` and `Connection` directly to the constructor of the `Command`.

Don't hold the connection open while you update the user interface. Comparatively, this is a long process and too long to keep a connection open

This doesn't make any sense. You are resetting the `DataSource` to the same value numerous times. But, it won't work anyway because a DataReader is not a valid `DataSource`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource?view=netframework-4.8&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.DataSource)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.8)%3Bk(DevLang-VB)%26rd%3Dtrue#remarks

```
While Taldr.Read
            DataGridView1.DataSource = Taldr
End While
```

If all you are doing in you `Catch` is showing a message box, show it in the user interface.

```
Private ConStr As String = "DSN=TallyODBC_9000;PORT=9000;DRIVER=Tally ODBC Driver;SERVER={(local)}"

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try
        DataGridView1.DataSource = GetNames()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Function GetNames() As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using cn As New OdbcConnection(ConStr),
        cmd As New OdbcCommand("SELECT $Name FROM Ledger", cn)
        cn.Open()
        Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            dt.Load(reader)
        End Using
    End Using
    Return dt
End Function
```

Comment: Hi mary, First of all thanks for all the detailed walk thought my code and improvements.
I tried your simplification code. and im getting Provider error as you anticipated. however the solution from @Jimi has worked for me without any provider

Comment: [https://drive.google.com/file/d/15Wqep7JYAdzc5-ejxPFSTPgVD5wDZEyq/view?usp=sharing]

Comment: Replacing "Oledb" with ODBC has worked for me                                                                   Dim dt As New DataTable

        Using cn As New OdbcConnection(ConStr),
                cmd As New OdbcCommand("SELECT $Name FROM Ledger", cn)

            cn.Open()

            Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                dt.Load(reader)
            End Using
        End Using
        Return dt

Comment: @CA.RajeshAppari I am so sorry. error on my part. Of course it should be ODBC. I don't think I had an imports set up for OdBC and it was filled in by intellisense with OleDb and I never notice. Sorry for my error. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Even though your problem is solved I am replying to thread
As you are using ODBC connection which is dependent on ODBC driver,
you will get issues if you change system or want to use multiple systems

Better approach to fetch data from tally is using XML API,
You no need to change any configuration you can use the same config as you did for ODBC
Since you want only Ledger Names you can use below code that fetches ledger names and posts to data from a2
Change company Name in XML in `<SVCURRENTCOMPANY>ABC Company</SVCURRENTCOMPANY>` tag
even multiple companies opened in tally it fetches data from target company

```
Public Sub GetTallyLedgersList()
Dim xmlhttp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60, myurl As String

Dim objXML As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

myurl = "http://localhost:9000"
xmlhttp.Open "POST", myurl, False
xmlhttp.send "<ENVELOPE><HEADER><VERSION>1</VERSION>
<TALLYREQUEST>Export</TALLYREQUEST><TYPE>Data</TYPE><ID>List Of Ledgers</ID></HEADER><BODY><DESC><STATICVARIABLES><SVEXPORTFORMAT>$$SysName:XML</SVEXPORTFORMAT><SVCURRENTCOMPANY>ABC Company</SVCURRENTCOMPANY></STATICVARIABLES>" & _
    "<TDL><TDLMESSAGE><REPORT ISMODIFY=""No"" ISFIXED=""No"" ISINITIALIZE=""No"" ISOPTION=""No"" ISINTERNAL=""No"" NAME=""List Of Ledgers""><FORMS>List Of Ledgers</FORMS></REPORT><FORM ISMODIFY=""No"" ISFIXED=""No"" ISINITIALIZE=""No"" ISOPTION=""No"" ISINTERNAL=""No"" NAME=""List Of Ledgers"">" & _
    "<TOPPARTS>List Of Ledgers</TOPPARTS><XMLTAG>ListOfLedgers</XMLTAG></FORM><PART ISMODIFY=""No"" ISFIXED=""No"" ISINITIALIZE=""No"" ISOPTION=""No"" ISINTERNAL=""No"" NAME=""List Of Ledgers""><TOPLINES>List Of Ledgers</TOPLINES><REPEAT>List Of Ledgers : FormList Of Ledgers</REPEAT><SCROLLED>Vertical</SCROLLED>" & _
    "</PART><LINE ISMODIFY=""No"" ISFIXED=""No"" ISINITIALIZE=""No"" ISOPTION=""No"" ISINTERNAL=""No"" NAME=""List Of Ledgers""><LEFTFIELDS>NAME</LEFTFIELDS></LINE><FIELD ISMODIFY=""No"" ISFIXED=""No"" ISINITIALIZE=""No"" ISOPTION=""No"" ISINTERNAL=""No"" NAME=""NAME""><SET>$NAME</SET><XMLTAG>NAME</XMLTAG></FIELD>" & _
    "<COLLECTION ISMODIFY=""No"" ISFIXED=""No"" ISINITIALIZE=""No"" ISOPTION=""No"" ISINTERNAL=""No"" NAME=""FormList Of Ledgers""><TYPE>Ledger</TYPE></COLLECTION></TDLMESSAGE></TDL></DESC></BODY></ENVELOPE>"

Set objXML = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
k = xmlhttp.responseText
If Not objXML.LoadXML(k) Then  'strXML is the string with XML'
    Err.Raise objXML.parseError.ErrorCode, , objXML.parseError.reason
End If
Set Nameslist = objXML.SelectNodes("//LISTOFLEDGERS/NAME")
 
 Count = 2
 ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Ledger Names"
For Each Name In Nameslist
s = Name.nodeTypedValue
ActiveSheet.Cells(Count, 1).Value = s
Count = Count + 1
Next

End Sub
```